exporting saved wifi hotspots and passwords
In my android 10 phone I am trying to find the file that contains my saved wifi hotspots and passwords, but cannot locate it.
In linux its common to see the wifi ssid and passwords stored in wpa_supplicant.conf or /etc/network/interfaces
ive tried via adb and also checking the userdata parition.
